# Help to make UBUNTU GNOME look like CentOS

Tags: gnome-classic, ubuntu-gnome

I'd like to make Ubuntu GNOME look like CentOS. If you look at screen shots you can see that CentOS is using some sort of classic session.

[Screenshot of CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/Screenshots)

I tried added the GNOME 3 PPA, but it doesn't seem to have the classic session.

[Gnome PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_3)

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I swear, CentOS is big (in everything and even size), old and stuff. GNOME is pretty, new, small, and just, new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do, is select gnome classic in the login screen, and install the gnome shell extension "Activities Configurator" (to disable the hotcorners). Through gnome tweak tool you can enable a "Places" drop down menu. I think that it is not possible to move application launchers to the top panel. An [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToElf.jpg) depicting all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

To install Gnome classic, the best bet that you have is by installing `gnome-session-fallback` (have tested this only on trusty 14.04 lts). This can be done by typing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Also, if you want to escape the hassle, then your another option is by installing [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).